# How can MEF AssemblyCatalogs be used with custom AssemblyLoadContexts

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-assembly, mef

I am working on an ASP.NET Core API that is extensible with Plug-Ins. Because the Plug-In Assemblies need to be unloadable, I've started loading them into separate, collectible, [AssemblyLoadContexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext?view=net-6.0).

**The Implementation basically looks like this:**

```
// Creating a new Context for the Plugin.
AssemblyLoadContext context = new AssemblyLoadContext(directoryInfo.FullName, true);
...

// Loading every Assembly the Plugin uses into the Context.
Assembly assembly = context.LoadFromAssemblyPath(fileInfo.FullName);
...

// Creating AssemblyCatalogs with the Assemblies.
AssemblyCatalog assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(assembly);
```

This works and I can use the Assemblies normally. However, the [AssemblyCatalogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.assemblycatalog?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) all have unpopulated Parts Properties and thus will not compose.

Now, if I load the Assemblies into the Default Context (`AssemblyLoadContext.Default`), everything works as expected, except the unloading of course.

What am I missing? Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out I've made a mistake. My Plug-In Project had `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` set to `true` and because of this, copied the NuGet dependencies to the output directory. Since I would then just copy the output to the directory the API loads its Plug-Ins from, the API tried to load these referenced libraries as well. Now, both the API and Plug-In Project reference `System.ComponentModel.Composition` and - long story short - the DLL was loaded twice, in different versions. The API was using `6.0.0` and the Plug-In was using `4.0.0`.

Because of this, the attribute comparison (MEF finds its exports by looking for the `ExportAttribute`) would later fail which is why the `AssemblyCatalog` was not able to find the Exports.

[image]